# Very basic Java nested for loop issue

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm having a hard time trying to get this code to start at 5 spaces and reduce to 0 spaces, subtracting a space every line.

```
public class Prob3 {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        for (int x=1; x<=5; x++)
        {
            for (int y=5; y>=1; y--)
            {
            System.out.print(" ");
            }
        System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Current output is (should be 5 spaces):

```
      5
      4
      3
      2
      1
```

I'm happy with the progress so far but I need to get something closer to this:

```
        1
      2
    3
  4
5
```

I feel like I'm pretty close

Comment: @Zeb homeworks are very well accepted on SO, given that OP has tried it himself, and has shown his/her attempt in the question.

Comment: Nevermind! I just got it after hours of fussing with it. Wohoo! Edit: Thank you all for the quick replies, first time using S.O.

Comment: Yes, but giving an answer with no explanation doesn't help him in the long run. If it is it should be tagged.

Comment: @Zeb. `homework` tag is deprecated on SO. And I think some answers are too obvious to be added with any explanation.

Comment: If he couldn't figure it out, it deserves an explanation.

Comment: @user2840304 Don't edit the question with solution. You can mark one of the answers as accepted by clicking the tick mark besides each answer.

Comment: I was reluctant to use this because I didn't want a quick answer, I went back to my Professor's slides and he had an example with the exact answer posted below and it all clicked.

Out of curiousity, why wouldn't it work the way before? To me it looks like both should output the same.

Comment: @user2840304. will add an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your inner loop to:

```
for (int y=5; y > x; y--)
```

You would notice a pattern in the number of whitespaces on each row:

- Row 1 = 4 whitespaces
- Row 2 = 3 whitespaces
- Row 3 = 2 whitespaces
- so on..

So, the pattern is, the number of whitespaces is `5 - rowNumber`. In your code the outer loop denotes the `rowNumber`. And the inner loop should run `5 - rowNumber` of times. That is why the condition should be `y > rowNumber`, i.e. `y > x`.

Comment: the inner loop condition should be 'y > x' actually.

Comment: ooh, ok! Now I can see it! +1

Answer (score 1):

Change your inner loop to this:

```
for (int y=5; y>x; y--)
```

Full Code:

```
for (int x=1; x<=5; x++)
{
     for (int y=5; y>x; y--)
           System.out.print(" ");

     System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner for loop expression should be:

```
public class Prob3 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            for (int y = (4 - x); y > 0; y--) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(x + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was that you were starting at 5 each time. The (4-x) in the inner loop is so that the last number (5) has 0 leading spaces.